# How to parse args in another class?

Tags: java, args

I have an issue about parsing args. I have a write method which is in `WriteToFile` class like this:

```
public class WriteToFile {  

    public void write (String text){
        try{
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            write.write(text);
            write.newLine();
            write.close();
        }
        catch (Exception error){
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public class A {

    WriteToFile write = new WriteToFile();
    write.write(something);

}

public class B {

    WriteToFile write = new WriteToFile();
    write.write(something);

}
```

We need to change **"output.txt"** to **args[1]**. Normally adding one more argument to method is the solution but allowed only 3 line code changes. I tried to add a set method but write method used by multiple classes so it takes more than 3 lines to fix it. I tried to extend main class to get into scope, didn't work. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "but allowed only 3 line code changes"?

Comment: `but allowed only 3 line code changes` why is it so?

Comment: well adding it as an additional paramater, changing `output.txt` to the parameter and passing an extra parameter from the main seems like 3 lines of code for me

Comment: @KevinEsche but we need to change all called methods.

Comment: @Emredağıstan what are all called methods? i only see one.

Comment: @Emredağıstan is the main method in the WriteToFile class?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No main method is in Main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create new public field in the `WriteToFile` class (fileName)

2) from main `myWriter.fileName = args[1]`

3) `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, true);`

// no change to the method signature called 100 times

**Edit**

If you are constructing many instances of WriteToFile all over the place, then use a static field in `Main`

1)  In `Main` `public static String fileName;`

2)  from main `Main.fileName = args[1]`

3)  `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(Main.fileName, true);`

Comment: Yes but many classes using this method and other classes except main, I cant access args[1] variable. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Emredağıstan The value for fileName is set at the beginning of the program in `main` using args[1].  If you are constructing many instnces of `WriteToFile` all over the place then you should keep this variable in a static field in `Main`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a parameter and using it when you call the method would only take three changes:

```
// Change 1 - add a fileName parameter to the method
public void write (String text, String fileName) { 
    try{
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, true); // Change 2 - use it
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(writer);

        write.write(text);
        write.newLine();
        write.close();
    }
    catch (Exception error){
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Change 3 - in the main method that calls this one, pass args[1]:
myWriter.write("someText", args[1]);
```

Comment: What if we already called this method about 100 times in 1500 line?

Comment: @Emredağıstan can you share your method calling this one? I fear we need some more context to help you with this problem.

Comment: @Emredağıstan If calling multiple times is the problem, why not just use Find and Replace?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void write (String text, String filename) // 1
{
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename,true); // 2
   ...
```

In your main, do this while calling.

```
new WriteToFile().write(text, args[1]); // 3
```

These are exactly 3 line changes as shown by comments.